# Why is the callback not being executed?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm writing a basic web application (begin with seaside) but the callback never runs...any ideas?

```
renderContentOn: html

  | group |
  html form: [

    html text: 'Gender: '.
    group := html radioGroup.
    group radioButton
        selected: self contact isMale;
        callback: [ self contact beMale ].
    html text: 'Male'.
    group radioButton
        selected: self contact isFemale;
        callback: [ self contact beFemale ].
    html text: 'Female'.
    html break.

    html anchor
    callback: [ mmpiItems setAnswer: (self option) ];
    with: 'Next'.
 ]
```

Comment: I suspect that you're expecting AJAX requests to magically do what you want. Form element callbacks are (usually) triggered by submitting the form.  Try adding `html submitButton` to submit the form and click that button. The callback of the anchor, however, should work out of the box.

Comment: Max. You are right. That's the problem!

Answer (score 2):

An anchor inside the form does not submit the form, only a submitbutton does. This is not defined by Seaside but by HTML.

You can find more information in the seaside book on writing forms with Seaside: http://book.seaside.st/book/fundamentals/forms

Comment: That's the problem ... thank you very much.
Rookie error.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

You must use `submitButton` instead of an `anchor` or any other `button`.

Your code would look like this:

```
renderContentOn: html

 | group |
 html form: [
   html text: 'Gender: '.
   group := html radioGroup.
   group radioButton
     selected: self contact isMale;
     callback: [ self contact beMale ].
   html text: 'Male'.
   group radioButton
     selected: self contact isFemale;
     callback: [ self contact beFemale ].
   html text: 'Female'.
   html break.
   "Use a submitButton instead of a regular anchor/button"
   html submitButton
     callback: [ mmpiItems setAnswer: (self option) ];
     with: 'Next'.
   ]
```